# Jquery AJAX response not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response

For some reason this jQuery function is not working properly. Here's my code... the response div is not updating with my response.

#### WHEN AJAX FUNCTION IS CALLED

```
if ($action == 'sort') {

    echo 'getting a response';
    return 0;

}
```

#### JQuery FUNCTION

```
function sort() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contributor_panel.php?action=sort",
        data:"sort_by=" + document.getElementById("sort_by").value +
             "&view_batch=" + document.getElementById("view_batch").value,
        success: function(html){

            $("#ajaxPhotographSortResponse").html(html);

        }
    });
```

}

#### DIV TO REPLACE

```
<div id="ajaxPhotographSortResponse"></div>
```

Comment: Is the AJAX call loading successfully? You can test that with Firebug. Or do an alert() inside the success function.

Comment: why would you assume it will *always* work successfully? add a callback for error handling and you'll be able to debug your code better.

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't think the AJAX call is loading... when I trigger the function by selecting something in my dropdown box nothing shows up in firebugs script tab.

Comment: Is there a particular browser this happens in? Have you tried console.log(html) to see what you're getting back from the server?

Comment: Do you assign $action=$_POST['action']; ?

Comment: A callback is like your success function -- it gets called when you get a successful return from your ajax call.  So if you're falling into your success callback, what data are you seeing being returned from your server?  What's Firebug telling you about the response?  Also, are you sure you're falling into the `if` block in your PHP code?

Comment: I put an alert in the ajax function and it is not triggering so the ajax function isn't calling.

Comment: @ D Hoerster Firebug isn't giving me a response at all, the ajax function is not calling for some reason.  And yes the if block is definitely calling.

Comment: @ Centurion No, I assign $_REQUEST['action'] since the action is in the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `action=sort` into the data property of the $.ajax function. You're making a POST request, but appending data onto your query string like a GET request. `Data` only appends to the query string if it's a GET request.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contributor_panel.php",
        data: {action:'sort', sort_by: $('#sort_by').val(), view_batch: $('#view_batch').val()},
        success: function(html){

            $("#ajaxPhotographSortResponse").html(html);

        }
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating the arguments you are passing to your server side script I would recommend you using the following syntax. Also if you already use jQuery you no longer need the `document.getElementById` function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contributor_panel.php?action=sort",
    data: { sort_by: $("#sort_by").val(), view_batch: $("#view_batch").val() },
    success: function(html){
        $("#ajaxPhotographSortResponse").html(html);
    }
});
```

or even shorter using the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$('#ajaxPhotographSortResponse').load('contributor_panel.php?action=sort', 
    { sort_by: $("#sort_by").val(), view_batch: $("#view_batch").val() });
```